# All partial derivatives are $0$ $\Rightarrow$ $f$ is constant.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $\emptyset \neq U\subset \mathbb R^n$ is open and path-connected, and let $f:U\to \mathbb R$ be $C^1.$

And suppose
$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}
\equiv \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}
\equiv \cdots \equiv \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}\equiv 0.$

Then, prove that $f$ is constant on $U$.

---

Somehow, I think that $f$ is independent of $x_1$ since $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}
\equiv 0$, is independent of $x_2$ since $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}
\equiv 0$, $\cdots$ ,is independent of $x_n$ since $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}
\equiv 0$, and therefore $f$ is constant.

But of course, this is not a decent proof and this didn't use the path connectedness of $U$.

How can I use the supposition and prove the claim ?

Comment: I would use the fact that if $x\neq 0$ is fixed then there is some $c$ on the line segment connecting $0$ and $x$ such that $$f(x)-f(0)=\nabla{f}(c)\cdot (x-0)$$ You can easily prove this by applying the MVT to the function $t \mapsto f(tx)$ on the domain $[0,1]$

Comment: "$f$ is independent of $x_1$ since $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}=0$". Be more explicit about why this is true, and then you'll see where the assumption about $U$ is used.

Comment: the theorem is true even under the weaker assumption that $f$ is differentiable on $U$ (continuous differentiability is not needed), using the mean-value inequality. With continuous differentiability though, a simple proof can be given using the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hypotheses imply $U$ is connected (path connected implies connected). Put an equivalence relation on $U$ defined by $x \sim y$ if $f(x) = f(y)$. Show that each equivalence class $[x]$ is open in $U$, i.e. if $f(x) = C$, then there is an open ball $B$ around $x$ such that $f = C$ on $B$ (here is where you use the mean value theorem). Use connectedness of $U$ to conclude that there can only be one equivalence class.

Comment: In order to use the connectedness of $U$, do I have to show that not only $[x]$ is open but also $[x]$ is closed ? @Mason

Comment: @Luca No. Once you know that the equivalence classes are open, it follows that there can only be one of them since otherwise $U$ would be the union of two or more nonempty disjoint open sets.

Comment: Point taken. Thank you for explaining.